# Error: 400: Bad Request: there is no photo in the request

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

I use telegraf and when send photo by url become such problem but when I use local photo(../img.jpg) it is okey. Code:

```js
bot.hears(/\/pic/, ctx=> {
  let photo = 'https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/azmpDRN_460s.jpg';
  bot.telegram.sendPhoto(chatId,
    {source: photo},
    {caption: "Hello"});
});
```

Comment: I think your problem is that the code expects the source as a "binary" and you give it a link. If you want to send a photo by a link you should firs download it...

Comment: Hmm, first I don't connect telegraf so use such command: bot.sendPhoto(chatId, url_photo, { caption: 'Picture' }) where I can call picture by url, and now I take telegraf as it is easier to use but had such problem. So I can't first download it. Maybe is some other option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to change 'source' to 'url':

```js
bot.hears(/\/pic/, ctx=> {
  let photo = 'https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/azmpDRN_460s.jpg';
  bot.telegram.sendPhoto(chatId,
    {url: photo},
    {caption: "Hello"});
});
```